# Improve Response Time: Directory Services account management

Tags: c#, performance

I am creating a tool to assist with managing account rights. Initially I implemented Add User functionality but response time/performance of output is slow. Is it possible to retrieve output quickly or improve response time?

Code Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DirectoryServicesPlay
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Original();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Original()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("getting domain context");
        var userContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        Console.WriteLine("getting user");
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(userContext, "c123456");

        Console.WriteLine("getting machine context");
        var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "ABCDEFGHI1", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, "c123789", "test123");

        Console.WriteLine("getting group");
        var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, "Administrators"); //Response time is slow

        Console.WriteLine("adding member");
        group.Members.Add(user); //Response time is slow

        Console.WriteLine("saving group");
        group.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("getting members");
        var members = group.GetMembers();

        Console.WriteLine("iterating members");
        foreach (var member in members) // Response time is slow to retrieve and display each member information.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", member.Name,member.SamAccountName); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably not relevant, but just in case ... Take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4237/Querying-Active-Directory-using-NET-classes-and-LD and in particular a comment I wrote there 5 years ago "Basic design fault?".